# Show that $\mathcal{C}$ generates $\mathcal{E}_I$.

Tags: probability-theory

I can see that $\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i \subset \mathcal{C}$. But, if we want to say that $\mathcal{C}$ generates $\mathcal{E}_I$, we have to show the equality $\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i = \mathcal{C}$, right? But, I don't know how to show this. Suppose $A \in \mathcal{C}$. Then, there exists $\cap_{i \in J} A_i  = A$. I don't think $\cap_{i \in J} A_i$ is necessarily an element of $\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i $ because not every subset of $A_i \in \mathcal{E}_i$ is an element of $\mathcal{E}_i$. I think I am missing something...  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal C$ generates $\xi_I$  by  does not mean $\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i = \mathcal{C}$. It means $\sigma (\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i) (=\xi_I$) = $\sigma (\mathcal{C})$.
Each member of $\mathcal C$ is a finite intersection of sets from $\xi_I$ and $\xi_I$ is a sigma algebra. Hence $\mathcal C$ is contained in $\xi_I$ and so $\sigma (\mathcal C)$ is also contained in $\xi_I$.